# How do I change markers transparency when I apply notboxplot function for generating beeswarm boxplot?

Tags: matlab, plot, boxplot

I am using notboxplot from Rob Campbell (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26508-notboxplot) to generate beeswarm boxplots. I am wondering is it possible that I can change the transparency of the markers (dots) in the plots? Here is the code of changing the size/face color/edge color of the marker. But I can't use *markerfacealpha* to change the transparency here.

```
P = notBoxPlot(random(10,10));
set([P.data],'MarkerSize',4,...    
    'markerFaceColor',[0.4,0.4,0.5],...
    'markerEdgeColor', 'none')
```

Is there any way to change the transparency with using this function?

Comment: It looks like you would have to edit the notboxplot code to use scatter rather than plot.  See https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/325258-how-can-i-make-the-plot-function-markers-and-lines-transparent-using-alpha-or-otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @nhowe in the comment, you cannot use `markerfacealpha` with the function plot.

In the "Generate scatter in X" part, you can replace `plot` by `scatter`.

```
% Generate scatter in X
thisX=violaPoints(thisX,thisY);
C=cols(k,:);
h(k).data=scatter(thisX, thisY, 'o',...
                  'markerfacecolor', C+(1-C)*0.65,'markerfacealpha',0.5);
```

Instead of:

```
 % Generate scatter in X
 thisX=violaPoints(thisX,thisY);
 C=cols(k,:);

 h(k).data=plot(thisX, thisY, 'o', 'color', C,...
                'markerfacecolor', C+(1-C)*0.65);
```

Noticed that I fixed the `markerfacealpha` value to 0.5 which is not really clean. But you get the principle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible. `[P.data]` is an array of Line objects. And :

> Line series objects do not support transparency (alpha) values.

As stated [on Mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103074-how-can-i-set-the-transparency-of-line-objects-in-matlab-7-14-r2012a#answer_112419.)

So you need to modify the source code as proposed by @obchardon.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I wanna set the transparency of the markers instead of lines in a beeswarm boxplot

Comment: Rather than simply kicking the OP to a link, it might be better for **future visitors** if you would [edit] your answer to summarize why you believe it isn't possible, then provide the link for more details.  See **Provide Context for Links** at [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).